# From two mutable Sets check elements that do not overlap - kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have one mutableSet schoolStudents and an array of strings student.

```
var schoolStudents: MutableSet<String>?
var students: Array<String>?
```

I cast the students to a mutable set:

```
students?.toMutableSet()
```

I need to find the students that are not in schoolStudents. If they all are, return all of them.

Can I use :

```
schoolStudents.minus(students)
```

But I am getting an error that boolean is required but Set was found. What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Using minus should have worked. https://pl.kotl.in/ikFFFlGlf

Comment: Note that both collections are nullable. What is your expected result if one of them or both are nulls?

Comment: use `.subtract()` instead [see this](https://pl.kotl.in/rq9RCMLWm)

Comment: `(students ?: emptyList())` maybe the nullability is the problem.

Comment: Whenever you can, get rid of the nullable types... Maybe you imported some other `minus`-function?

Comment: Are you invoking `students?.toMutableSet()` without doing anything with the result and then trying to subtract the array from the set?

Comment: Terminology: `students?.toMutableSet()` is a **conversion**, creating a new `MutableSet` instance with the same items as your array. A **cast** would be `students as MutableSet`, promising the compiler that it's _already_ a `MutableSet` instance (which would of course throw a ClassCastException in this case, because it's not).